# Writing to a DataOutputStream Variable Error in Java

Tags: java

I currently have the following HTTP Client. Every time I try send a second request to the server I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: printStackTrace
    at clientpersistent.ClientPersistent.main(ClientPersistent.java:84)
Java Result: 1
```

Here is the client code:

```
Socket ClientSocket = new Socket(ClientHostName,1991);

            /*We simply open the input and output buffers for our connect
             * We do this so that we can read and write to the connection between our client and server
             */
            BufferedReader InputClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClientSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream OutputClient =new DataOutputStream(ClientSocket.getOutputStream());

            OutputClient.writeBytes("GET /my.html HTTP/1.0\r\n");
            OutputClient.writeBytes("Host: localhost:1991\r\n");
            OutputClient.writeBytes("Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n");
            OutputClient.writeBytes("Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n");
            OutputClient.writeBytes("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n");
            OutputClient.writeBytes("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36\r\n");
            OutputClient.writeBytes("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n");
            OutputClient.writeBytes("Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n");
            OutputClient.writeBytes("\r\n");

            /*Here we are simply displaying to the screen the response from the server for the flie we asked for*/
            String s;
            while ((s = InputClient. readLine()) != null) 
            {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

             Thread.sleep(1000);

            //ERROR HAPPENS HERE!!
            OutputClient.writeBytes("GET /download.jpg HTTP/1.0\r\n");
            OutputClient.writeBytes("Host: localhost:1991\r\n");
            OutputClient.writeBytes("Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n");
            OutputClient.writeBytes("Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n");
            OutputClient.writeBytes("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n");
            OutputClient.writeBytes("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36\r\n");
            OutputClient.writeBytes("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n");
            OutputClient.writeBytes("Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n");
            OutputClient.writeBytes("\r\n");
            while ((s = InputClient.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            //Here we close the the read and write buffers and the socket connection
            OutputClient.close();
            InputClient.close();
            ClientSocket.close();
```

Comment: Are you using NetBeans? If you search for "Uncompilable source code" here on StackOverflow, you'll find questions and answers about similar problems which seem to have to do with NetBeans.

Comment: Indeed I am using Netbeans I'd give it a search